# How to block 'people also ask' in Google Search

Tags: google-search

There's a very similar question here:

[How to stop Google's "people also search for"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115038/how-to-stop-googles-people-also-search-for?newreg=6361c77b9db84be38fa76ef9a14f82e6)

But I'm not familiar with urls or code and am generally very inept. While I've tried the element zapper, the zapper seems to only zap on a per-search basis. Like each search is different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop Google's "people also search for"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115038/how-to-stop-googles-people-also-search-for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of July 2022, this works (using [AdBlock filter syntax](https://adblockplus.org/filter-cheatsheet) that you can enter in e.g. [uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock)):

```
www.google.*##div[data-initq]
```

This will probably not work forever. It's a cat and mouse game. One could probably find a cleverer AdBlock query that would be more robust.