# How to get rid of Mathway, GeoGebra, QuickMath, and Symbolab stuff?

Tags: google-search

When I Google search "arccos(-14/sqrt(30*68))=" (or any similar calculation), I just want Google to give me the number.

But instead Google first shows me this useless stuff from Mathway, GeoGebra, QuickMath, and Symbolab:

[image]

I have to scroll down before I see what I want:

[image]

How can I get rid of the Mathway, GeoGebra, QuickMath, and Symbolab stuff?

(I have uBlock origin. Is there maybe some code I can add to block the above?)

---

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. Some blocks have buttons and links. Click them and tell us what they do. The three vertical dots buttons should show a menu. What are the options of those menus?

Comment: @Rubén: Just privacy policies: See my added screenshot

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115038 https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/163717

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
arccos(-14/sqrt(30*68))=
```

type

```
arccos(-14/sqrt(30*68)) in radians
```

or click https://www.google.com/search?q=arccos(-14%2Fsqrt(30*68))+in+radians

Below is the top of the search results shown to me:

[image: Results]

The page didn't include Mathway, GeoGebra, QuickMath, and Symbolab.

- Removing "in radians" has a very similar result, just the units are "rad" instead of "radians".
- Using "in degrees" has a very similar result, just the units are "degrees" instead of "radians".
- Using "degrees", the scientific calculator is shown below the result.

  [image: Results showing the scientific calulator]

---

The above resulted from trial and error.

This works for me using the following:

- google.com
- Signed in using my main account
- Display language: English
- Results language: English
- Region: Current (Mexico)
- Web browser: Chrome
- Operative System: macOS Sonoma

Your mileage might vary: Depending on your context, you might have a different experience using Google (websearch). If the suggested query doesn't work for you, you could look at the parameters listed above and others and try changing them, including changing the search query.

## Resources

### Related Help Article

- [Learn search tips & how results relate to your search on Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/10563935?hl=en)

Comment: I don't understand how this helps me or is more convenient than simply scrolling down?

Comment: @user103496 Click this [https://www.google.com/search?q=arccos(-14%2Fsqrt(30*68))+in+radians](https://www.google.com/search?q=arccos(-14%2Fsqrt(30*68))+in+radians)

Answer (score 1):

### Omit The Equals Sign

Equals signs don't normally help or hurt Google Search calculator functions, although I don't normally include them.

Leaving out the equals sign `=` solves it so seems like the simplest aporoach:

```
arccos(-14/sqrt(30*68))
```

[image]

### Other Approaches

If leaving in the equals sign adding `calc` or `calculate` before or after the calculation addressed it as well.

```
calc arccos(-14/sqrt(30*68))=
```

Adding brackets around the whole thing also works:

```
(arccos(-14/sqrt(30*68))=)
```

As does simply adding the opening bracket and skipping the closing one:

```
(arccos(-14/sqrt(30*68))=
```